# Why updating @State inside AppDelegate does not work?

Tags: swiftui

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @State var isFocused: Bool = true
    
    var window: NSWindow!

    // Some window setup code here

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        isFocused = true
    }
    
    func applicationDidResignActive(_ notification: Notification) {
        isFocused = false
    }
}
```

I tried to print `isFocused` value and it is always `true` even immediately after `isFocused = false` statement. Is `@State` only working inside `SwiftUI` Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation:

> ```
> /// A linked View property that instantiates a persistent state
> /// value of type `Value`, allowing the view to read and update its
> /// value.
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> @frozen @propertyWrapper public struct State<Value> : DynamicProperty {
> ```

So, `State` is for SwiftUI `View`, but `AppDelegate` is-not-a `View`.

Comment: I see! then using Combine is an alternative solution. ~Is that also the reason why the `false` value could not be assigned?~ Tested and yes, it is the reason.